# Writing Objective Function using scipy.optimize.minimize Troubleshoot

Tags: scipy, constraints, scipy-optimize-minimize, objective-function

I am trying to solve an optimization problem applied to bridges, in the context of a parametric design. The objective function is to try and split precast barriers into a minimum amount of unique barriers. There are two kind of barriers, normal and barriers with light poles. I have shared an image with a bridge of 3 spans.

The parameters are as follows:

The light pole barrier width is equal to **w**.

The light pole barriers are evenly spaced by the parameter **s**.

The light pole starting point is defined by the variable **a**.

The **spans** of the bridge, [l1,l2,...ln]

**x** is  the width that all of the equations will have to be divisible by.

The idea is to as many barriers with the width of x and some remaining lengths to fill the spans kept at a minimum. I have to get all the distances **[a,b,c,...f]** in an array of equations (see picture), where I am also appending the light between the special barriers **(s-w)**, and have all of them divisible by **x**. I also added in the elements **arr** array to account for constants in case the remaining length is not divisible by x so we will compensate with a different barrier (basically, we use that constant to subtract).

Here is a sketch of what I am talking about:
[image: bridge]

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

s = 12500  
spans = np.array([25450, 25100, 25450])
ejs = np.zeros(len(spans)-1)  # expansion or separation joints . ignore for now

min_bw, max_bw  = 0, 1200  #light pole barrier width

consts = abs((len(spans) * 2 - 1))  # Number of distance elements [b,c,d...]
init = np.array([1500, 1500, 6250]) #x, w, a + w/2

n = (spans - s / 2) // s  # consecutive spacings of barriers for a given span. At times we have more 
m = np.ones(len(spans) * 2)  # the length of the equation array that has to be divisible

def objective(arr, n, s, spans, ejs):

    x = arr[0]
    w = arr[1]
    a =  arr[2] # (the offset is until the mid axis of the light pole)
    m = np.ones(len(spans) * 2 + 1) # We make room for the last constraint h=(s-w)
    m[0] = a - w / 2 

    for i in range(1, len(spans) * 2):
        j = (i - 1) // 2
        if i % 2 == 0:
            m[i] = (s - w) - (m[i - 1] + ejs[j] + arr[2 + i])
        else:
            m[i] = spans[j] - (m[i - 1] + n[j] * s + w + arr[2 + i])
    m[-1] = s - w  # We also need the light distance between two poles to be divisible by x
    #print(m)
    return np.sum(m%x)

#Bounds
bounds = np.array([(1500, 2100), (1500, 2600), (3000, s)])
extras = np.repeat([(min_bw, max_bw)], consts, axis=0) # Add the bounds for each additional element
all_bounds = np.concatenate((bounds, extras), axis=0)


initial = np.pad(init, (0, consts), 'constant', constant_values=min_bw)

sol = minimize(fun=objective, x0=initial, bounds=all_bounds, method='Nelder-Mead', args=(n, s, spans, ejs))
print(np.round(sol.x))

#m = [ 5500. , 5950.,  5050.  ,6050.  ,4950. , 6500. ,11000.] #the print m statment
```

The problem that I can't seem to figure out is that the `np.sum(m%x)` does not return 0! I get the right distances in the m array compared to the drawing. The divisibility equation constraints are not satisfied yet the function says it terminates successfully. I'd appreciate any insights! Thank you so much!

Comment: The divisibility captured here is not a constraint, it's an objective. The minimizer will happily pick a solution where the objective is not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problems that Nick calls out are true (though not comprehensive): there are many local minima, and the objective is non-differentiable.

But just as importantly: your objective isn't well-suited as an objective at all - it should be a constraint; and this entire system (when re-constructed) is linear. That means it's time for integer linear programming, which has better guarantees of convergence and accuracy than a generic `minimize` (no matter which method you select). More specifically, you're doing constraint programming, where there is no objective at all. (Or maybe you have some idea of what a better objective *should* be, such as minimizing the coefficients of x).

In addition to the variables for x, w, a, your "distance elements" and m, you also need a binary selection matrix of which multiple of x is equal to m. This gets around the problem that multiplication of x by some multiple to get m is non-linear, by using so-called big-M constraints.

I've tried to make this easy-to-follow, and at any point you can call `some_constraint.A.toarray()` and view the result in e.g. PyCharm's matrix visualiser to see what's happening; but you may also need to dig into some introductory material on linear programming to get a better handle on it. Anyway, the results seem sane.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
from scipy.optimize import milp, Bounds, LinearConstraint

s = 12_500
spans = np.array((25_450, 25_100, 25_450))
ejs = np.zeros(len(spans) - 1)  # expansion or separation joints
min_bw, max_bw = 0, 1200  # light pole barrier width
consts = spans.size*2 - 1  # Number of distance elements [b,c,d...]
m_count = spans.size*2 + 1
n = (spans - s/2)//s  # consecutive spacings of barriers for a given span

# In the old solution's objective for the initial guess, m/x ranges from 3.6 to 7.3. Ballpark 20 as a maximum.
mul_count = 20
multiples = np.arange(1, 1 + mul_count)[:, np.newaxis]

'''
Variables: x, w, a, consts, m, and then
a m_count * mul_count matrix of selectors of integer multiples of m.
Each selector is binary (0 or 1), and indicates times 1, times 2, ... times mul_count respectively.
'''

# Constraint matrix for all m equations, starting with the 'm' term itself
m_A = sp.hstack((
    sp.csc_array((m_count, 3 + consts)),
    -sp.eye(m_count),
    sp.csc_array((m_count, m_count*mul_count)),
), format='lil')

# Column positions: x, w, a, consts, m, mi
# First row: a - w/2 == m0: -0.5w + a - m == 0
m_A[0, 1:3] = -0.5, 1
# Middle rows
m_A[1:, 1] = -1  # -w (middle and last row)
m_A[1:-1, 3: 3+consts] = -sp.eye(consts)  # -consts
m_A[1:-1, 3+consts: 3+consts+m_count - 2] -= sp.eye(m_count - 2)  # -m[i - 1]

m_rhs = np.empty(m_count)
# First row
m_rhs[0] = 0
# Even rows: m[i] = s - w - m[i-1] - ejs[(i - 1)//2] - consts
#            -s + ejs[(i - 1)//2] = -w - m[i] - m[i-1] - consts
m_rhs[2:-1:2] = ejs - s
# Odd rows: m[i] = spans[(i - 1)//2] - (m[i - 1] + n[(i - 1)//2] * s + w + arr[2 + i])
#            -spans[(i - 1)//2] + n[(i - 1)//2]*s = -m[i] - m[i - 1] - w - consts
m_rhs[1:-1:2] = n*s - spans
# Last row: m[-1] = s - w
#           -w - m[-1] = -s
m_rhs[-1] = -s

constraint_m = LinearConstraint(A=m_A, lb=m_rhs, ub=m_rhs)
# To see the constraint matrix: view constraint_m.A.toarray() in a matrix viewer

# Exactly one selector per m-variable must be on
constraint_selection = LinearConstraint(
    A=sp.hstack((
        sp.csc_array((m_count, 3 + consts + m_count)),
        sp.kron(
            A=sp.eye(m_count),
            B=np.ones(mul_count),
            format='csc',
        )
    )),
    lb=np.ones(m_count),
    ub=np.ones(m_count),
)

'''
Enforce the multiple constraint:
m >= x*i                     m <= x*i       (if mi is selected)
-i*x + m >= 0                i*x - m >= 0   (if mi is selected)
-i*x + m + M(1 - mi) >= 0    i*x - m + M(1 - mi) >= 0
-i*x + m - M*mi >= -M        i*x - m - M*mi >= -M
Column positions: x, w, a, consts, m, mi
'''
ix_m = sp.hstack((
    np.tile(multiples, (m_count, 1)),
    sp.csc_array((m_count * mul_count, 2 + consts)),
    sp.kron(
        -sp.eye(m_count),
        np.ones((mul_count, 1)),
    ),
))
M = 1e6  # big-M constraint coefficient
mmi = -M*sp.eye(m_count * mul_count)
constraint_mul = LinearConstraint(
    A=sp.bmat((
        ( ix_m, mmi),
        (-ix_m, mmi),
    )),
    lb=np.full(shape=2*m_count*mul_count, fill_value=-M),
    ub=np.inf,
)


result = milp(
    c=np.zeros(3 + consts + m_count + m_count*mul_count),  # There is no optimization objective
    integrality=np.concatenate((
        np.zeros(3 + consts + m_count),  # x, w, a, consts and m continuous
        np.ones(m_count * mul_count),    # mi integral
    )),
    bounds=Bounds(
        lb=np.concatenate((
            (1_500, 1_500, 3_000),  # x, w, a
            np.full(shape=consts, fill_value=min_bw),  # consts
            np.zeros(m_count + m_count*mul_count),     # m, mi
        )),
        ub=np.concatenate((
            (2_100, 2_600, s),  # x, w, a
            np.full(shape=consts, fill_value=max_bw),   # consts
            np.full(shape=m_count, fill_value=np.inf),  # m unbounded
            np.ones(m_count*mul_count),  # mi are binary, so 0-1
        )),
    ),
    constraints=(
        constraint_m,
        constraint_selection,
        constraint_mul,
    ),
)
assert result.success, result.message
(x, w, a), distances, m, mi = np.split(result.x, (3, 3+consts, 3+consts+m_count))
mi = mi.reshape((m_count, mul_count))
multipliers = (mi @ multiples).ravel()

print(result.message)
print(f'x = {x}')
print(f'w = {w}')
print(f'a = {a}')
print(f'distance elements = {distances}')
print(f'm = {m}')
print(f'm/x quotients: {m/x}')
print(f'multipliers = {multipliers}')
print('multiply selectors =')
print(mi)
```

```
Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
x = 1650.0
w = 2600.0
a = 6250.0
distance elements = [450.   0. 100.   0. 450.]
m = [4950. 4950. 4950. 4950. 4950. 4950. 9900.]
m/x quotients: [3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 6.]
multipliers = [3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 6.]
multiply selectors =
[[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

The problem is of fairly small size and high sparsity, so solves quickly. You can visualise the constraint sparsity pattern via

```py
plt.imshow(
    np.sign(
        sp.vstack((
            constraint_m.A,
            constraint_selection.A,
            constraint_mul.A,
        )).toarray()
    ),
)
plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

[image: constraint pattern]

Comment: @Nick ODell,. Superheroes do not wear capes! I am truly humbled and overwhelmed by your solutions. I cannot thank you enough for your answers. I will take a deep dive into LP soon.                                                                         I've drawn your solution from the print statement Reinderein and it's here:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1OBn.png].                                          The m array that holds the lengths to be divisible are not the correct ones. We would have the m = [4950, 5400,4500, 5500, 4400, 5950 & 9900]

Comment: With a drawn solution [450, 1200, 550,1100, 1000],  and is different than what the  optimization algorithm gives.  Does your algorithm attempt a solve on the least amount of unique elements in the distance_elements array? (I see 450 repeats twice so it does pair values but that solution unfortunately isn't right)  Best case scenario we would have 0 elements (hardly likely) and at worst we will have 5 elements (2*spans -1) as it is now, meaning that we will have to construct 5 different barrier types to fill the gaps that the green barriers can't, the ones with width of x.

Comment: @DragosSeculin Perhaps you meant to at me. Anyway, back-calculating m from the solution using your own objective produces the exact same results as mine. Perhaps there's something in the statement of the objective that's off. Please examine that in your code, and if it needs to change let me know.

Comment: I am sorry for hinting that your solution was wrong.I found the culprit. I was mislead to believe that the  light pole barriers are placed with an offset. Actually the bridge starts with the lightpole and the optimization is correct! I really thank you both as both your answers were correct. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3MR5.png]. However, I noticed the spacing between the light barriers is not constant and slightly altered. I think doing this reduces the number of types, but what if we constrain the light pole barriers to the spacing 12500 mm variable? How would your code change?

Comment: I'll edit the answer to show that; also, is there a different objective that you care to minimize? Value of x, multiples of x, something else?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to have as few  barrier types apart from the light pole ones as possible in the entirety of the bridge. Like the solution it found previously [450,0,100,0,450] would indicate 4 barriers in total. 1. x, 2. w, 3.x+450, 4. x+100. That's ideal actually. Only problem with the spacing not being constant. If I come with a solution with >6 barriers people will start doing the barrier layout manually ..  So in that regard, I guess, have as many zeros in the resulting solution array as a goal? The offset of the first light pole barrier should be bounded [0,s/2 = 6250]

Comment: Sorry, what does `[0,s/2 = 6250]` apply to? The first "distance element" that had been found as 450? Previously you had bounded this at `[0, max_bw = 1200]`. Is that not correct?

Comment: If all of the "const" `min_bw` and `max_bw` constraints are replaced with 12,500 for all five variables, the problem is infeasible.

Comment: Given the original constraints, it does not seem possible to increase the number of zeros in [450, 0, 100, 0, 450].

Comment: Wait, there has been a little confusion. Apologies. What I meant for the bounded parameter, I meant the **a** parameter in the original picture(first picture in my question). It's the distance, that would be used to place the first light pole barrier. In our recent solution, the **a** is 0, hence the first light pole barrier is placed without offset. The **min_bw** & **max_bw** are the constraints that the solution will have to satisfy. I place an upper limit to the maximum width the new barrier type will satisfy to fill the remaining gaps and 0 when we don't have to put any. Is it clear now?

Comment: So then, **[0, s/2 = 6250]** applies  to the first placement of the barrier. It can be 0, just in our case, but I would also want to be able to adjust if needed. The end user will do a trial & error to see which solution works best by playing with the spacing of light poles **s**  and the **offset 'a' -> [0,s/2 = 6250]**.  **min_bw & max_bw** can stay the same. Once the optimization finishes, for each start & end of a given span, I will look at the solution array, and for every element !=0 I will extend the leftmost barrier x+ sol[0], x+sol[1] creating new types. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: The constraints and the bounds, will be given parameter inputs in the form of sliders for the user to adjust with. I'll do that with Grasshopper, a visual programming interface. Probably, configuration wouldn't be the best as we limit the exploration space if the user tightens the inputs, but it should be under his control. I can always revert to default values. So far, these are the constraints.

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm having difficulty correlating your diagram, your descriptions and your variable names. Perhaps you should make a github project and document these things.

Comment: Renderien, you've done so much already. I'd like to thank you again for putting in  the time. I can already use what you've wrote and I will incorporate that. I am left in awe by the understanding you and @Nick ODell have on the subject. I would hope some day I can reach a level of understanding comparable to yours. You've both hinted to linear algebra and linear programming, but do you happen to have any book in mind? Thanks.

Comment: I first learned from the [GLPK manual](https://hpc.nih.gov/apps/glpk/latest/glpk.pdf). Broad math or linear-algebraic questions to do with LP are well-received on [Operations Research](https://or.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You're running into two problems.

1. `m % x` has a derivative that confuses the optimizer.
2. The problem you're solving has lots of local minima.

Let's start by giving the optimizer more information about how to optimize your function.

### Confusing derivative

The function `minimize()` is a local optimizer. If there is another minimum that it would have to climb up a hill to get to, it cannot reach it.

Lets say you wanted to minimize the function f(x) = x % 100, with x bound between 50 and 150. Here is a graph of this function.

[image: graph of f(x) = x % 100]

Suppose the optimizer starts at x = 90. It looks at the derivative, and moves down the slope to the left. Then, it gets stuck at x = 50. The same thing is happening in your problem.

What you can do to solve this is to create a function which rewards the optimizer for getting closer to x = 100. I came up with this function, which is a cosine wave which gets close to zero when `variable` is a near-multiple of `target`.

```
def modular_difference(variable, target):
    # Move valley very slightly forward
    overshoot_distances_amount = 1e-8
    distance_to_next = variable % target / target
    distance_to_next -= overshoot_distances_amount
    ret = -np.cos(2*np.pi*distance_to_next) + 1
    return ret
```

(Note: The purpose of `overshoot_distances_amount` is explained later.)

This gives the following graph:

[image: cosine approximation]

This tells the optimizer it should move toward x=100 if it is at x=99.

I integrated this new function into your code in the following way.

First, I changed the original objective function so that it returns both m and x. Call this `objective_inner()`.

```
def objective_inner(arr, n, s, spans, ejs):
    x = arr[0]
    w = arr[1]
    a =  arr[2] # (the offset is until the mid axis of the light pole)
    m = np.ones(len(spans) * 2 + 1) # We make room for the last constraint h=(s-w)
    m[0] = a - w / 2 

    for i in range(1, len(spans) * 2):
        j = (i - 1) // 2
        if i % 2 == 0:
            m[i] = (s - w) - (m[i - 1] + ejs[j] + arr[2 + i])
        else:
            m[i] = spans[j] - (m[i - 1] + n[j] * s + w + arr[2 + i])
    m[-1] = s - w  # We also need the light distance between two poles to be divisible by x
    return m, x
```

Then, I wrote two versions of the objective function.

```
def objective_differentiable(arr, n, s, spans, ejs):
    m, x = objective_inner(arr, n, s, spans, ejs)
    return modular_difference(m, x).sum()


def objective_old(arr, n, s, spans, ejs):
    m, x = objective_inner(arr, n, s, spans, ejs)
    return np.sum(m%x)
```

The first function is a version of your objective that has nice derivatives, using sine waves. The second function is the same as your original objective.

However, fixing the derivative is not sufficient by itself. It still gets stuck in local minima.

### Global optimizers

Some functions cannot be optimized by local optimizers, because the optimizer gets trapped in a local minimum. This is one of them.

To get around this, I used the [basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html) function, which uses a local optimizer, but also takes large steps in random directions, with the hope of finding a better minimum.

I found the following worked well.

```
minimizer_kwargs = dict(bounds=all_bounds, method='Nelder-Mead', args=(n, s, spans, ejs))
sol = basinhopping(objective_differentiable, x0=initial, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs, niter=100)
print("basinhopping sol", sol)
sol = minimize(fun=objective_old, x0=sol.x, bounds=all_bounds, method='Nelder-Mead', args=(n, s, spans, ejs))
print("minimize true sol", sol)
```

This does the following:

- First, it uses basinhopping with Nelder-Mead as the local optimizer, optimizing the differentiable version of your objective.
- Then, it passes the solution this found to your original objective. I did this so that it is easy to compare whether it is finding a better solution than the original. (Note: this is why `overshoot_distances_amount` exists in the code above. This picks a solution which is slightly after the point where the modulo wraps around, which makes it easier for the optimizer to find the exact minimum of `objective_old()`.)

This can find solutions which get a score of 1e-4 or less on your original objective.

Here's one of the solutions it finds:

```
array([1501.43791458, 1989.93457535, 5499.28104559,  449.99999353,
          0.000001  ,  100.00001273,    0.00000361,  450.00000564])
```

Comment: Thank you Nick.  Your explanation was really helpful. I understand now how it works.